# How to color a rule node in LuaTeX?

Tags: color, luatex, rules

When I do something like this:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[english]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\directlua{
    COL = node.subtype ( "pdf_colorstack" )
    WHAT = node.id ( "whatsit" )
    color_push = node.new ( WHAT, COL )
    color_pop = node.new ( WHAT, COL )
    color_push.stack = 0
    color_pop.stack = 0
    color_push.command = 1
    color_pop.command = 2
    color_push.data = "1 0 0 rg"

    local function test ( head )
        for n in node.traverse_id ( node.id ( "disc" ), head ) do
            head = node.insert_before ( head, n.prev, node.copy ( color_push ) )
            head = node.insert_before ( head, n, node.new ( node.id ( "rule" ) ) )
            head = node.insert_after ( head, n.next, node.copy ( color_pop ) )
            n.prev.subtype = 0
            n.prev.width = 50000
        end
        return head
    end

    luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "pre_linebreak_filter", test, "test" )
}

\begin{document}

movement

\end{document}
```

I get the following result:

[image]

How can I color the rule node, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rg` only colors filled outlines while the stroke color is set with `RG`. So you need `1 0 0 rg 1 0 0 RG` in order to set both.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess this is exactly the reason why I also posted [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642065/where-to-find-information-about-coding-luatex-pdf-literal-whatsits) question. ;-)
If you could help me with that one as well it would be much appreciated.